# MySQLが日本語化しない

Tags: mysql

MySQLで日本語を扱いたいのですが、文字コードの関係で扱うことが未だできません。
my.iniを変更しましたが、全く変わりません。

mysqlで `status;` を打ち込むとこのような結果がでます。

```
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
```

Server characterset と Db characterset が「latin1」なのが問題なのでしょうか。もし、そうでしたら変更方法を教えていただきたいです。できればもうずっと日本語に対応できるようにしたいので根本解決をしたいです。

環境
Windows10
MySQL 5.7

Comment: 変更を加えた後の `my.ini` の内容も質問中に含めておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。また、設定ファイルの変更後に mysqld (サービス) の再起動は実施しましたか？

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？ [文字コードを設定する](https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/myini/index3.html)

Comment: 日本語を扱いたいテーブルやフィールドのcharactersetも教えて下さい